# Get Jira Tickets from .NET to create release notes?

Tags: .net, jira

Some background: I would like to automatically create a readme.txt or release.txt file for my project from Jira. For that I would like to know if there is a way to retrieve all closed tickets starting a given ticket Id for project X? I was thinking to do that from my nant script or maybe from my c# code. Is this is a good way or are there better practices?

Answer (score 2):

What Jira version?  I'm on 3.13 and there is a release notes page already there.

Comment: I'm on 3.7.4, and I don't see that. How do you get to it?

Comment: On the road map page. Next to the version number is a link to "release notes"

http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/v3.7.1/roadmap_report.html